# MySQL folder missing on the Program Files folder, so I cannot set up the path on the environment variables

Tags: mysql, xampp

Basically I want to run an old project, I installed and XAMPP 5.6.14, I want to setup my database and I need to do it via console, so as the title says, the MySQL folder is missing, I never did the installation of MySQL on my pc using the official installation from MySQL.

Previously I used the newest version of XAMPP and the folder was there, I was able to set up the database but stumbled with a project that needed an older version of PHP, that's why I installed an older XAMPP on my PC

Comment: If you install XAMPP it should come with a database anyway. It's a bit unclear what the issue is, or what environment variables exactly you need to set up. And are you sure it didn't just install the database files in a different folder or something? I'd expect the XAMPP control panel can probably give you some details

Comment: @ADyson basically i need to set up environment variables on windows to make the mysql commands work on the terminal, if i don't set up this variable, i cannot import another database that i need because the regular import function on the XAMPP is throwing me an error. I was not able to find the MySQL folder anywere else, don't know what could be happening.

Comment: Ok so, as I mentioned previously, when you go into the xampp control panel, what does it tell you about your mysql setup? You should be able to see the status of the mysql service, look at its logs and view its config (which should then tell you a path to find it on the disk)